# How to convert a column in data.frame from characters to POSIXct?

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a column of date to POSIXct form. However, all the data here are not able to use as.POSIXct to convert since the day of the date are included. I tried using gsub(".* Friday, .*","",data) to remove all "Friday" but it is not working. What can I do here? Thank you. I tried to search this kind of problem but I didn't get a satisfied answer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Directly with lubridate:

```
library(lubridate)
mdy("Friday, December 7, 1787")
[1] "1787-12-07"
```

But, POSIXct requires time and you don't have it. Therefore your class will be "Date".

If you really want a POSIXct then:

```
mdy_hms(paste("Friday, December 7, 1787", "00:00:00" ))
"1787-12-07 UTC"
```

Comment: There's a comment posted as an [answer by Jared Pace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45226502): "I've used POSIXct without time (just a date). As I understand, it looks for time but it is not necessary."

Comment: I don't see much point on it but since POSIXct is by definition Date-time